# How to use routes attributes macros for multiple methods in Actix-Web

Tags: rust, actix-web

In the [Actix Web Framework](https://github.com/actix/actix-web), how does one use the route attributes macros (`#[http_method("route")]`) to bind multiple http methods to one function?

For example, I have this trivial endpoint:

```rust
/// Returns a UUID4.
#[get("/uuid")]
async fn uuid_v4() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().json(Uuid {
        uuid: uuid::Uuid::new_v4(),
    })
}
```

I would like to have the same endpoint handle `HEAD` requests, **how do I do this?**
My initial approach was to just stack up the macros:

```rust
/// Returns a UUID4.
#[get("/uuid")]
#[head("/uuid")]
async fn uuid_v4() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().json(Uuid {
        uuid: uuid::Uuid::new_v4(),
    })
}
```

But I do get a compilation error:

```
    |
249 | async fn uuid_v4() -> impl Responder {
    |          ^^^^^^^ the trait `actix_web::handler::Factory<_, _, _>` is not implemented for `<uuid_v4 as actix_web::service::HttpServiceFactory>::register::uuid_v4`
```

*I have gone through the `actix-web` and `actix-web-codegen docs` and didn't find anything addressing this*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do

```
#[route("/", method="GET", method="POST", method="PUT")]
async fn index() -> impl Responder {
  HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello world!")
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
  HttpServer::new(move || {
    App::new()
        .service(index)
  })
  .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
  .run()
  .await
}
```

Answer (score 7):

An example with multiple path and multiple methods for one resource

```
async fn index() -> impl Responder {
  HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello world!")
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
  HttpServer::new(move || {
    App::new()
        .service(
            actix_web::web::resource(vec!["/", "/index"])
                .route(actix_web::web::get().to(index))
                .route(actix_web::web::post().to(index))
            )
  })
  .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
  .run()
  .await
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use multiple macros for a single function since mid 2022 (see [this](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/pull/2718) github issue)

Example:

```
#[routes]
#[get("/")] #[head("/")]
#[get("/index")] #[head("/index")]
#[get("/index.html")] #[head("/index.html")]
async fn index() -> impl Responder {
    // HttpResponse::Ok().finish()
}

// In main():
App::new().service(index)
```

Answer (score -3):

I assume you are using `actix-web: 2.0.0` with `actix-rt: 1.0.0` and this handler you are passing to `App.service` method like below

```rust
HttpServer::new(move || {
            App::new()
                .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
                .service(index)
        })
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", self.port))?
        .workers(8)
        .run()
        .await
```

then you will need to write handler like this ->

```rust
/// Returns a UUID4.
#[get("/uuid")]
async fn uuid_v4(req: HttpRequest) -> Result<web::Json<IndexResponse>> {
    let uuid_header = req
        .headers()
        .get("uuid")
        .and_then(|v| v.to_str().ok())
        .unwrap_or_else(|| "some-id");
    //curl -H "uuid: username" localhost:8080

    println!("make use of {}", uuid_header);
    Ok(web::Json(Uuid {
        uuid: uuid::Uuid::new_v4(),
    }))
}
```

Comment: I do not understand how this supports anything else apart from the `GET` method.